# preg_match_all to get list of virtual hosts from httpd-vhosts.conf file xampp using php preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex, xampp

This is what i tried, also i dont want the hosts and explanations which are commented with #/ ##

```
$str = '# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn\'t need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option \'-S\' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>



##<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ##ServerName CI1
    ##DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_1\public
##</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName CI2
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName CI3
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public
</VirtualHost>';
```

##### Pattern 1

```
$pattern1 = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
preg_match_all($pattern1, $str, $match);
```

##### Pattern 2

```
$pattern2 = "/^(?<!#).*<$tagname.*>(.+?)<\/tagname>/mis";
preg_match_all($pattern2, $str, $matches);
```

##### Function

```
function everything_in_tags($str, $tagname)
{
    $pattern1 = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match_all($pattern1, $str, $match);
    
    $pattern2 = "/^(?<!#).*<$tagname.*>(.+?)<\/$tagname>/s";
    preg_match_all($pattern2, $str, $matches);
    
    echo '<pre>',print_r($match[1]),'</pre>';
    
    echo '<pre>',print_r($matches[1]),'</pre>';
}

everything_in_tags($str, $tagname);
```

##### Output for Pattern 1

```
Array
(
    [0] =>  block.
#
##
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##
    [1] => 
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##
    [2] => 
    ##ServerName CI1
    ##DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_1\public
##
    [3] => 
    ServerName CI2
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public

    [4] => 
    ServerName CI3
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public

)
```

##### Output for Pattern 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    ServerName CI3
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public

)
```

##### Desired Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => array(
        [ServerName] : CI2
        [DocumentRoot] : D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public
        ),
    [1] => array(
        [ServerName] : CI3
        [DocumentRoot] : D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public
        );
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, coz i'm new to regex..... Also i don't needany of the strings which are commented with #/##, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use as a regex:

```
'~^\s*<VirtualHost\s+[^>]*>\s*ServerName\s+(?P<ServerName>\S+)\s*DocumentRoot\s+(?P<DocumentRoot>\S+)\s*</VirtualHost>~m'
```

Then what you need will be in capture groups 1/'ServerName' and 2/'DocumentRoot'.

**Explanation:**

1. `^` - Match start of line with `m` flag set.
2. `\s*` - Match 0 or more whitespace characters.
3. `<VirtualHost` - Match '<VirtualHost'.
4. `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespace characters.
5. `[^>]*` Match 0 or more characters that are not '>'.
6. `>` - Match '>'.
7. `\s*` - Match 0 or more whitespace characters.
8. `ServerName` - Match 'ServerName'.
9. `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespace characters,
10. `(?P<ServerName>\S+)` - Match 1 or more non-whitespace characters as capture group 'ServerName'.
11. `\s*` - Match 0 or more whitespace characters.
12. `DocumentRoot` - Match 'DocumentRoot'.
13. `\s+` - Match 1 or more whitespace characters,
14. `(?P<DocumentRoot>\S+)` - Match 1 or more non-whitespace characters as capture group 'DocumentRoot'.
15. `\s*` - Match 0 or more whitespace characters.
16. `</VirtualHost>` - Match '</VirtualHost>'.

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ynce1q/1/)

**The code:**

```php
$regex = '^\s*<VirtualHost\s+[^>]*>\s*ServerName\s+(?P<ServerName>\S+)\s*DocumentRoot\s+(?P<DocumentRoot>\S+)\s*</VirtualHost>~m';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Prints:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName CI2
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public
</VirtualHost>
            [ServerName] => CI2
            [1] => CI2
            [DocumentRoot] => D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public
            [2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_2\public
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName CI3
    DocumentRoot D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public
</VirtualHost>
            [ServerName] => CI3
            [1] => CI3
            [DocumentRoot] => D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public
            [2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter_3\public
        )

)
```

**Update**

The above regex assumes that the DocumentRoot specification contains no embedded spaces, which may not always be the case. It also had an extraneous, unnecessary `s*`, which I have removed. The following regex, I believe, is an improvent. It replaces `\S+`, which matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters with `.+?`, which will *non-greedily* match 1 or more of *any* character (except for the newline character). Since it is followed by `\s*</VirtualHost>`, being *non-greedy* it will stop matching as soon as it finds '</VirtualHost> optionally preceded by any whitespace.

So the new regex would be (used with the `m` flag):

```
^\s*<VirtualHost\s+[^>]*>\s*ServerName\s+(?P<ServerName>\S+)\s*DocumentRoot\s+(?P<DocumentRoot>.+?)\s*</VirtualHost>
```

[See new RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ArBOjR/1/)

```python
$regex = '^\s*<VirtualHost\s+[^>]*>\s*ServerName\s+(?P<ServerName>\S+)\s*DocumentRoot\s+(?P<DocumentRoot>.+?)\s*</VirtualHost>~m';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, you really saved my time, i spent more than 2 days searching for this in google, but no answers helped me. once again i'm really sorry that i cannot upvote since i dont have a reputation of 15. but an infinity upvote from my side. Thank you